# Error in submit form with ajax and send mail in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying submit custom form written in header.php with ajax and send mail to particular email address with submitted data,but getting error of 404 in console, form validation is performs taht means jquery file is loaded but when trying to call ajaxurl to send mail it gives 404 error. I am 100% sure that error is in ajax call or need to make function in function.php for sending mail but can't solve it out, can anyone help me solve out this issue?

Form in header.php

```
<form id="wp_con_form" method="post">
  <ul class="form-list wp_contact_form_ul cf">
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *" class="text-field wp_con_frm_name">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone *" class="text-field wp_con_frm_phone">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email *" class="text-field wp_con_frm_email">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="agency" id="agency" placeholder="agency" class="text-field ">
    </li>
    <li class="full">
      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message *" class="text-field wp_con_frm_message"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li class="form-button">
      <input type="submit" value="Send" id="wp_con_frm_btn" class="button" />
    </li>
    <div class="wp_cont_form_msg"></div>
  </ul>
</form>
```

calling jquery file in function.php is

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'themestyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css',false,'1.1','all' );

wp_localize_script("themestyle","the_ajax_theme", array("ajaxurl_anyName" => admin_url("admin-ajax.php")));
```

Jquery file for validation and ajax call

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready(function(){
function validateContact(){
        var output = true;
        j('.wp_contact_form_ul li').removeClass('wp_cont_frm_err_msg');

        if(!(j(".wp_con_frm_name").val())){
            j(".wp_con_frm_name").parent().addClass('wp_cont_frm_err_msg');
            output = false;
        }

        if(!(j(".wp_con_frm_phone").val())){
            j(".wp_con_frm_phone").parent().addClass('wp_cont_frm_err_msg');
            output = false;
        }

        if(!j(".wp_con_frm_phone").val().match(/^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/))
        {
            j(".wp_con_frm_phone").parent().addClass('wp_cont_frm_err_msg');
            output = false;
        }           

        if(!(j(".wp_con_frm_email").val())){
            j(".wp_con_frm_email").parent().addClass('wp_cont_frm_err_msg');
            output = false;
        }

        if(!j(".wp_con_frm_email").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/))
        {
            j(".wp_con_frm_email").parent().addClass('wp_cont_frm_err_msg');
            output = false;
        }           

        if(!(j(".wp_con_frm_message").val())){
            j(".wp_con_frm_message").parent().addClass('wp_cont_frm_err_msg');
            output = false;
        }
        return output;
    }

    /* send contact form data to email */

    function afterSubmit(getobj)
    {
        if(getobj.status)
        {           
            j('#wp_con_form')[0].reset();
            j('#wp_con_form .wp_cont_form_msg').html(getobj.message).slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp();             
        }
        else
        {                               
            j('#wp_con_form .wp_cont_form_msg').html(getobj.message).slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp(5000);                 
        }   
    }   

    j('#wp_con_frm_btn').click(function(){
        var output = validateContact();
        if(output){
            var dataString = j("#wp_con_form").serialize();
            j.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajaxurl,
                dataType:"json",
                data: dataString,               
            }).always(function(data)
            {           
                afterSubmit(data);
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

code for sending mail in function.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];
$to      = 'yourname@example.com';

$subject =  'List Qwick';
$message =  'Name: '.$name. "\r\n" .
            'Phone: '.$phone. "\r\n" .
            'Email: '.$email. "\r\n" .
            'Message: '.$msg. "\r\n" .

$headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    $getMessage = '<p class="success">Your Email Has Been Sent Successfully</p>';           
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'message'=>$getMessage));
}
else 
{   
    $getMessage = '<p class="error">Mail function not working..</p>';           
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>0,'message'=>$getMessage));
}
```

Comment: Can you please check at what url is the data posted in  the console->network ?

Comment: You can use contact form 7 plugin for this purpose.

Comment: This question will be closed, as all you have done is dumped your code and asked why it doesn't work. We need more evidence as to what you have tried, and where you think the error is. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the Ajax URL available for JavaScript, you're actually creating an object called `the_ajax_theme`, and one of its properties is called `ajaxurl_anyName` and contains your Ajax URL.

```
wp_localize_script( 'themestyle', 'the_ajax_theme', array(
    'ajaxurl_anyName' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
) );
```

In your Ajax call, you're trying to access the `ajaxurl` which doesn't exists. To use the value that you're actually defining, you have to use the names you defined in your `wp_localize_script()`. So, your Ajax call should look like this:

```
j('#wp_con_frm_btn').click(function(){
    var output = validateContact();
    if(output){
        var dataString = j("#wp_con_form").serialize();
        j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: the_ajax_theme.ajaxurl_anyName,
            dataType:"json",
            data: dataString,               
        }).always(function(data)
        {           
            afterSubmit(data);
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

I'd recommend to use shorten names like `themeSlug.ajaxURL`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like ajaxurl is ever set, so you're getting a 404 on an "undefined" URL. Set that value and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible it needs the `admin-ajax.php` file from WordPress, for the form `action`.

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>" method="post">
```

Also, it doesn't look like you're defining `ajaxurl` in your JavaScript. Try adding this:

```
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
```

Add it above or below this line in your existing code:

```
var dataString = j("#wp_con_form").serialize();
```